# Black Body Curve Equation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, graphing-functions

Is there a simple equation ($y=f(x)$) that can give me the general shape of a [black body curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body)?

Here's an image by [Brews ohare](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Brews_ohare) to show you what I mean:

[image]

Is there a polynomial equation that can give a similar shape? It would be nice to have the horizontal asymptote at $y=0$, but isn't necessarily required if it would simplify the equation.

Comment: You can use the free SW 'LabFit' to find the best approximation of the Plank function given a set on N points taken from the curve. Obviously every temperature T will give a different curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [Planck's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law).